# (Android Studio) How to let documentation show library content correctly instead of showing library path?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, path, documentation, document

How to let documentation show library content correctly instead of showing library path?

[image]

Comment: Check file .idea/libraries/Gradle__androidx_activity_activity_1_0_0_aar.xml (or whatever is your actual library name), see if there is a valid <SOURCES>/<root> entity. If not, try to delete the file and do a Gradle reimport into IDE. It may also help to delete .idea directory (back it up first) and reimport.

Comment: @AlexeyBelkov  Thank you for answer. I have not try your method. But Thank you.